# Proof validation: Proving that the group of homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ is infinite

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I'm trying to solve the following exercice:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be any topological space and $G$ the set of all homeomorphisms of $X$ into itself. Then the set $G$ is a group under the operation of composition of functions and it's called the "Group of homeomorphisms of $X$"
>
> 1 - If $X=[0,1]$, show that $G$ is infinite.

So, my initial thought was to assume that $G$ is finite and then show that we can build a new homeomorphism from the elements of $G$ that it's not in $G$. So what I did was the following:

#### My proof:

Let's suppose that $G$ is finite. Then we have that, as every function $f\in G$ has an inverse function $f^{-1} \in G$, that $\text{card } G=2n + 1,n\in \Bbb N$. The "$+1$" part comes from the fact that the identity function $I$ is in $G$, but $I^{-1}$ is simply $I$

So, we can list the elements of $G$ as following:

$$G = \{f_1,...,f_n,f^{-1}_1,...,f^{-1}_n,I\}$$

So now, lets define a new function as following:

$$f'= f_1 \circ \left( f_2 \circ (... \circ \ f_n )\right)$$

So we have that: $\forall f \in G, f' \neq f$. But we have that $G$ is a group so it's closed under the operation $\circ$. This is a contradiction, meaning that the set $G$ can't be finite.

---

Is this proof correct? Because I assumed that $\forall f \in G, f' \neq f$, is this correct? Is this the most straight forward way of proving this? Because I sometimes find myself over-complicating proofs. Can you show me any other alternate ways of proving this?

Comment: You don't appear to have proved that there cannot be homeomorphisms of order $2$. You also don't appear to have proved that $f'$ does not lie on your list.

Comment: What is an homeomorphism of order 2? @DavidA.Craven

Comment: One that is equal to its own inverse. Order $n$ means the $n$th power of a map is the identity.

Comment: An example is $x\mapsto (x+1/2) \bmod 1$.

Comment: Here is a question to mull over. Could you adapt your proof to show that *every* group $G$ (perhaps such that $x\neq x^{-1}$ for all nontrivial $x$) is infinite?

Comment: Keep in mind, in many cases the best proof of existence is to construct the objects whose existence is asserted. This may require some mathematical imagination. in your problem, you'll need to first imagine, and then write down, an infinite family of formulas $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$, prove that each is a homeomorphism, and prove that no two are equal (which is what is done in the answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, you’ve overlooked the fact that a homeomorphism can be its own inverse; an example on $[0,1]$ is the function $f(x)=1-x$. And it’s really not clear that repeated composition is always going to give you a new function.

You would be better off actually constructing an explicit infinite family of autohomeomorphisms of $[0,1]$. Probably the simplest is the family of functions $f(x)=x^n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, though there are plenty of others. For instance, you might try to construct an uncountable family of piecewise linear autohomeomorphisms of $[0,1]$; this can be done in such a way that each function is defined on just two intervals, and the intervals are the same for all of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you haven’t prove that $f^\prime \neq f$, which is a flaw in your argumentation.

Also why to proceed by contradiction ? It is quite easy   to show an infinite set of homeomorphisms. For example $x \mapsto x^n$ with $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Or choose any $a\in (0,1)$, send $[0,1/2]$ to $[0,a]$, and $[1/2,1]$ to $[a,1]$. Indeed, this shows that the group is uncountable.